# Including Select Count(*) in Linq Query VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a query in MS Access that I'm trying to convert to vb.net. I'm migrating the code to use Linq.

vba query:

```
    SELECT SS,TitleNo,(select count(*) from [VendorRpts] where Delivery=5 and not(OrderDate is null) and applicationsidnumber=AIN
and not(VendServCode=VendSCID )) as PrefVendorCount 
From applications where applicationsidnumber=AIN
```

I started to write it:

```
Dim myApps = (From Apps In dc.APPLICATIONs
                      Where Apps.APPLICATIONSIDNUMBER = AIN
                      Select Apps.SS, Apps.TITLENO, )
```

However I don't know how to get the count.
Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Edil

Comment: Your subquery is not related to the main query or is `AIN` a column in `Applications`?

Comment: Is that right, that `AIN` and `VendSCID` are columns in `Applications`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count will always the same for every record, so in LINQ i would use a separate query:

```
Dim vendorReports = From vr In VendorRpts 
                    Where vr.Delivery = 5 AndAlso 
                    vr.OrderDate.HasValue AndAlso 
                    vr.ApplicationsIdNumber = AIN AndAlso
                    vr.VendServCode <> VendSCID
Dim vendorReportsCount = vendorReports.Count()

Dim myApps = From Apps In dc.APPLICATIONs
             Where Apps.APPLICATIONSIDNUMBER = AIN
             Select Apps.SS, Apps.TitleNo, prefVendorCount = vendorReportsCount
```

Note that following would be the right syntax if you needed a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) in LINQ:

```
Dim myApps = From Apps In dc.APPLICATIONs
             Where Apps.APPLICATIONSIDNUMBER = AIN
             Let vendorReports = From vr In VendorRpts 
                                 Where vr.Delivery = 5 AndAlso 
                                 vr.OrderDate.HasValue AndAlso 
                                 vr.ApplicationsIdNumber = Apps.AIN AndAlso
                                 vr.VendServCode <> VendSCID
             Select Apps.SS, Apps.TitleNo, prefVendorCount = vendorReports.Count()
```

Comment: Hi Tim,
Where does  the "and not(VendServCode=VendSCID )) " goes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Edil: i overlooked that. First i have to know where these columns come from

Comment: Tim, the VendServCode is a field from the VendorRpts table. I'm passing the AIN, and VendSCID as parameters to the function that executes the query. Thanks again.

Comment: @Edil: look at the modified version

Comment: Tim, one more question: Shouldn't it be andalso not(vr.VendServCode = VendSCID)? Thanks.

Comment: @Edil: Yes, you are right. Or `andalso vr.VendServCode <> VendSCID`

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. Edil